# stud ubuntu howto?

Tags: 12.04, init

I've just been looking at the stud init script as I thought perhaps I'm meant to create a stud.conf inside /etc/stud

However, in looking through the init script it would apppear that it loads stud.conf variables into the current environment.  This of course fails for some reason and you get a bunch of errors.

Worse still, stud source code doesn't work with environment variables.

Can someone tell me how you're actually meant to set up stud with init script as it would appear to be completely broken.

Maybe I can just disable the init script and call stud from rc.local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be rather easy.

Create a file in `/etc/stud` ending in .conf.

e.g. `/etc/stud/website.conf`

The contents should contain something like:

```
OPTIONS="-f 0.0.0.0,443 -b 0.0.0.0,80" CERT="/etc/stud/cert.pem"
```

Assuming your PEM certificate file is located in `/etc/stud/cert.pem`
This would provide TLS/SSL support to a webserver listening on port 80

STUD is definitely a much better performer than stunnel.